# How to fit a very large convolutional neural network into the GPU with Theano

Tags: memory-management, neural-network, gpu, theano, large-data

I'm trying to program a large deep neural network in Theano (several big convolutional layers for image recognition). The whole net does not fit into the GPU, therefore I need to divide the net some way. My question is:

Does anybody know where to find tutorials or sample code to address this problem? There are a lot of good tutorials and code for "small networks" but I don't find anything for big networks.

This is not a trivial problem, reducing the batch of images during training or reducing the number or size of the layers is not a solution.

I would appreciate any idea about how to design the network or managing the GPU.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do the network parameters alone fit into GPU memory?

Comment: No, they don't. That is the problem, the net has a lot of them.

Comment: To my knowledge, dividing nets across multiple gpus isn't supported in theano. There's some talk about addressing this but it's not straight forward and probably won't happen soon, check the theano mailing list.   There's a PR in beta to use float16 which might save you some space:
https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2908  Otherwise, if you absolutely need a net bigger than hardware (Titan Xs are 12 gb . . . ) check out torch7's nn and dp package, covnets that aren't too-too exotic should be easy to configure and, I believe, possible to setup for multi gpu processing.

Answer (score 1):

Although it degrades the performance, but you can use `theano.tensor._shared` instead of `theano.shared`. `theano.tensor._shared` forces the data to be stored on the CPU RAM. However, you should first compute the amount of memory required by the network using the following method and then separate the network parameters into GPU and CPU RAM accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as T
T.config.floatX = 'float32'
dataPoints = np.random.random((5000, 65536)).astype(T.config.floatX)
#float32 data type requires 4 bytes
sizeinGBs = 5000 * 65546 * 4 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 + (some small over-head constant which we can ignore safely)
```